# Refer to specific attribute ID in WordPress / WooCommerce in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this function that creates a download spec sheet button on every product page.

```
if(is_product())
{
    $link = get_the_title();
    $link =  str_replace(' ', '-', $link);
    echo '<div class="download">';
    echo '<a href="';
    echo bloginfo('url');
    echo '/pdf/Spec-Sheet-';
    echo $link . '.pdf';
    echo ' " title="Download Spec Sheet" target="_blank">';
    echo 'DOWNLOAD SPEC SHEET';
    echo '</a>'; 
    echo '</div>'; 
}
```

But I am now adding a bunch of products that will not require spec sheets. I have created an attribute `machine` which I have added to the products that require this button. (Attribute slug is `machine` and there is one value, slug is `machine-2`)

This is the code I am trying to use but it is failing, not sure why... Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
if(!is_product())
{
    $machines = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_machine');

    if($machines != '')
    {
        $link = get_the_title();
        $link =  str_replace(' ', '-', $link);
        echo '<div class="download">';
        echo '<a href="';
        echo bloginfo('url');
        echo '/pdf/Spec-Sheet-';
        echo $link . '.pdf';
        echo ' " title="Download Spec Sheet" target="_blank">';
        echo 'DOWNLOAD SPEC SHEET';
        echo '</a>'; 
        echo '</div>'; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get it working by removing the `!` in `if(!is_product())`. Just goes to show 1 small error changes the whole meaning of the code. Here is the working code if anyone else has a similar problem.

```
if(is_product());
{

  $machines = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_machine');

    if ( $machines != '' )
    {
        $link = get_the_title();
        $link =  str_replace(' ', '-', $link);
        echo '<div class="download">';
        echo '<a href="';
        echo bloginfo('url');
        echo '/pdf/Spec-Sheet-';
        echo $link . '.pdf';
        echo ' " title="Download Spec Sheet" target="_blank">';
        echo 'DOWNLOAD SPEC SHEET';
        echo '</a>'; 
        echo '</div>'; 
    }
}
```